# Is there any good e-material or web site to start up with spring and spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I mean to say like for html/css/jquery etc. we have [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) like that is there any web site or e-material for starting up with spring and spring security.

Comment: Is your question about: a) the spring security specific details, or b) web base application security in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the spring security documentation getting start steps.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going through this tutorial to see a concrete implementation:

- http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration.html (Part 1)
- http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html (Part 2)

It provides a description and example of every file you'll have to set up, and a download of the tutorial project at the end of each tutorial.